# Use Lucee 5 OSGi bundle in CFML

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, cfml, lucee

are there any OSGi bundles available by default/out of the box without explicitly installing it on the server itself?

If yes, how would the code look like? I tried it by myself but always got the error, that the bundle is not available for me.

`POIFSFileSystem=createObject("java","org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem","apache.poi","3.11.0");` [[source]](http://docs.lucee.org/guides/lucee-5/functions-tags.html#createobject-extended)

or

`dtf=createObject('java', 'org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat', 'org-joda-time', '2.1.0');` [[source]](http://docs.lucee.org/guides/lucee-5/osgi.html#can-i-benefit-from-osgi-somehow)

did not work.

My first intension was to try the two OSGi functions which are new in Lucee 5:

`manifestRead(myBundlePath)` and `bundleInfo(myBundle)`

Did I miss something or did I begin with a false assumption?

Comment: If you look in the server admin there is an option called "Info - Bundle (jar)" which shows you a list of the OSGi bundles that are installed by default, which is basically everything Lucee needs to perform most functions, e.g. interacting with a MySQL database. If you want to make use of a specific bundle, I believe you need to place it into the "bundles" directory for either the Lucee install or the web context. Once the bundle is in that directory Lucee can find it and your above commands should work.

Comment: Also, you might find the guy over at dev.lucee.org, which includes all the key contributors to the core, might be able to offer more help with this.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you. I'll try that out (Y)

Comment: "If yes, how would the code look like?" The code to do what??

Comment: "[code snippet] did not work." This is a meaningless statement. What did you expect it to do and what did it actually do? Was there an error message?

Comment: "'If yes, how would the code look like?' The code to do what??" --That was stated below.

Comment: "'[code snippet] did not work.' This is a meaningless statement. What did you expect it to do and what did it actually do? Was there an error message?" -- I expected the behavior explained in the docs. The first two snippets should create objects from bundles, the last two structures to be dumped. error message said: "The OSGi Bundle with name [apache.poi] in version [3.11.0] is not available locally (/[...]/bundles) or from the update provider (http://snapshot.lucee.org).". So I can't execute the last two code snippets.